# Cambiar perspectiva/vista

Tags: soporte

Hace un día se me cambio la perspectiva de la web de verse de esta forma :

[image: Antes]

A verse tal que así :

[image: Ahora]

Hay alguna forma de revertir este cambio? Fue un cambio automático al obtener el privilegio de `revisión`. Gracias

Comment: en el menu del navegador si lo estas usando se cambio de la vista de escritorio, vuelve a ponerle...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

La captura de pantalla corresponde a  la versión móvil. Para volver a la versión "normal" ve al pie de página y haz clic en el enlace "sitio completo".

Comment: Solucionado! Gracias por el dato!